# Creatiing custom Power Query Connector from Swagger definition

Tags: powerbi, swagger

Following the article from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-sdk-vs-code I am trying Swagger definition of a set of APIs I would like to quickly create queries from in Power BI.

I am trying to use the swagger definition from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fresnel-software/vitruvi-sdk/master/schema.json but I have the same problem from Swagger definitions I have created for API projects myself.

My code is as follows:

```
WorkspaceURL = "{hostname for my API endpoint}";

[DataSource.Kind="PowerBi.VitruviConnector", Publish="VitruviConnector.Publish"]
shared i365.LitFibre.PowerBi.VitruviConnector.Contents = () as table =>
    let
        // Pull the latest swagger definition from the site
        credential = Extension.CurrentCredential(),
        token = credential[Key],
        headers = [Authorization = "JWT " & Token],       
        newSwagger = Json.Document(Extension.Contents("schema.json")),
        swaggerRecord = Record.AddField(newSwagger, "host", WorkspaceURL),
        nav = OpenApi.Document(Binary.From(Json.FromValue(swaggerRecord)), [Headers = headers, ManualCredentials = true])        
    in
        nav;
```

I have extracted the swagger JSON and put it in a file schema.json within the project.

The API is protected, so part of the code above takes in a JWT token, when you set the Key `AuthenticationKind` credentials. It also puts in the `hostname` to be used in calling the API Endpoints.

When I build it locally, I then extract the .mez file and copy this into `C:\Users\{user}\Documents\Power BI Desktop\Custom Connectors` folder and open up Power BI Desktop.

I search for my Connector and as you can see from the image below, it brings up all the APIs, however when I access one it gives the error as you can see:

[image: Power Bi Desktop screenshot]

The only examples I can find in the Microsoft documentation are unprotected APIs, that don't require a JWT token. Not sure if this is the issue, and if so how to resolve it.

Any ideas, would be welcome.